# Problemas para cargar el paquete "car" en R

Tags: r

Estoy utilizando Jupiter con el Kernel de R, pero estoy teniendo problemas para cargar la librería "car".

Cuando utilizo el comando `library(car)` me indica el siguiente error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'car' in loadNamespace(j
> <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
> there is no package called 'foreign'

Luego trato de instalar el paquete "foreign" con el código `install.packages('foreign')` y me indica el siguiente error:

> Warning message: "package 'foreign' is not available (for R version 3.6.1)"

Por último, también he probado remover el paquete con el comando `remove.packages("car")` y lo he vuelto a instalar con `install.packages("car", dependencies = TRUE)`. No obstante, sigo teniendo los mismos errores y problemas.

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema parece ser que el paquete "foreign" no está disponible para esa versión de R, requiere una más actualizada (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreign/index.html). Adicionalmente he buscado en la web y he encontrado otro post que te podría ser útil (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922375/foreign-package-in-r).

En el post básicamente te aconsejan que lo más fácil sería actualizar la versión de R (4.0 o superior). Una alternativa es la que propone otro usuario (Mark Clements); según explica puedes emplear cualquiera de esos 3 códigos para obtener una versión más antigua del paquete "foreign" que sí sea compatible con tu versión. Si vas a usar alguno de los dos últimos, los binarios (/bin/) ten en consideración tu sistema operativo.

Soy bastante nuevo en R, pero si tienes cualquier problema no dudes en preguntar y haré lo que pueda :-)

Comment: Hola Gero! ya que haces referencia a una pregunta de SO, estaría bien que incluyeras en tu respuesta lo que se habla en dicha pregunta puede que el usuario no sepa ingles aparte de que tu respuesta quedaría muchísimo mejor

Comment: Pues tienes toda la razón, no había caído. Edito la respuesta

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. El problema lo pude resolver con la referencia en el enlace. ✌